# SP2010 workflow activity on SP2013

Tags: workflow-activity, sharepoint-designer

We have a custom workflow activity created for SP2010. Now we are deploying it to SP2013. It gets deployed but can't see it in SP Designer 2013.
Is there anyway I can reuse the activity as is in SP 2013 workflows?

Comment: Have you looked in the SP2010 platform workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013? Your activity will not be visible in SP2013 style workflows.

Comment: I've checked in SP2010 workflow as well, but could not find it there too.